# Get the file size of an image loaded into the image component in cq5?

Tags: java, jsp, aem

I'm working on a cq5 project and I need to restrict the file the size of images uploaded via the image component to about a 150kb. I have created a custom image component called "`customimage`" by copy, pasting and renaming the default image component.

The property "`fileReference`" returns the relative path of the file `(for instance "/content/dam/myProject/emea/logo.jpg")`. There is no property for the absolute path. Right now I have code written to check the size of the file in the customimage.jsp file I have some code that looks like

```
String path = (String)properties.get("fileReference","");

File file = new File(path);

double file_size = file.length();
```

Problem is that no mater what image I pass into the component, file_size returns 0.0. The project is in html 4 so I can't take advantage of the nifty javascript file I/O that `html5` added so it has to be done through the java. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way I should be approaching this problem in cq5?

Comment: What about [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2012/08/01/cq5-loading-an-image-from-a-resource-in-a-custom-image-renderer/)? Is it helpful?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *fileReference* attribute will give you the path to the image in the jcr repo, presumably the dam, and not a path on the file system, meaning the File constructor you are calling won't work.

Untested, but something along the lines of the following might work.

```
Resource r = resourceResolver.getResource(path);
Asset a = r.adaptTo(Asset.class);
Rendition rnd = a.getOriginal();
long size = rnd.getSize();
```